# How to get value in an object in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a variable with object like this in PHP code.

```
[{"author_id":2},{"author_id":1}]
```

How to get the value of **author_id**. thanks

Comment: The code you've posted isn't PHP code, it's JavaScript or JSON. You should clarify exactly how you're using it in PHP. Show us the actual PHP code that you have already.

Comment: Yes, I am coding in  PHP code Marcin, and I think to code print result in JSON, I just learn Laravel and this is my code http://dpaste.com/0Q95MNC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `json_decode` to convert the object in php and get it. Example:

```
<?php
$xx='[{"author_id":2},{"author_id":1}]';
$arr=json_decode($xx,true);
print_r($arr);
//Output: Array ( [0] => Array ( [author_id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [author_id] => 1 ) )
echo $arr[0]["author_id"];
//Outpu: 2
?>
```

Comment: The data does _not_ represent an object ;-)

Comment: But it represent  a json object :)

Comment: Hi arkascha and Ferhad Othman thanks for your comment and I just new in PHP and trying to learn Laravel. Actually this is my code http://dpaste.com/0Q95MNC

Comment: Yes @FerhadOthman All your comment really2 help me a lot. and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is serialized JSON Array with JSON objects inside.

```
$str = '[{"author_id":2},{"author_id":1}]';
$arr = json_decode($str, true);

foreach($arr as $item) {
   echo $item['author_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That data you posted is in JSON format. After decoding that standard format you can directly access the contents.

For the first entry that would simply be:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode('[{"author_id":2},{"author_id":1}]');
var_dump($data[0]->author_id);
```

The output obviously is:

```
int(2)
```

To access *all* entries have a try like that:

The output then is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
}
```